# reshape numpy adding extra dimension for lagged values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I'm having trouble reshaping a numpy array for a recurrent neural network. I have an array that looks like this

```
     10 day       15 day   25 day
24     295.775   275.283333   281.16
25     296.000   275.483333   281.56
26     295.825   275.500000   281.75
27     295.425   275.350000   281.91
28     295.275   294.883333   282.04
```

and when I turn this into a numpy array this will be of shape `(num_samples, 3 features)`

but what I need to do is turn this into (num_samples, timesteps, 3 features)

where the array looks like

```
[ [ [295.775   275.283333   281.16]
    [296.000   275.483333   281.56]
    [295.825   275.500000   281.75]
    [295.425   275.350000   281.91] ]
  [ [296.000   275.483333   281.56]
    [295.825   275.500000   281.75]
    [295.425   275.350000   281.91]
    [295.275   294.883333   282.04] ]
```

where here the resulting numpy array here has (number_samples, 4 timesteps, 3 features)

I've been trying to add new columns for lagged variables and reshaping but to no avail

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are after is simply this:

```
np.array([arr[i:i+4] for i range(len(arr)-4)])
```

Comment: actually now that I think about it that is essentially exactly what i want